# Router Navigate to ngx-bootstrap tabs Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngx-bootstrap

I have a component with four tabs (using ngx-bootstrap tabs) myprod,mysettings,etc. and I created four different routing for each tab(pointed to same component). and I used the below code for show the right tab on page load.

```
[routerLink]="['/user/my-account']" [routerLinkActive]="'active is-active'"
```

but unfortunately everytime the **active** class will add to the first to tab not the right one. If I use any other class name instead of **active** it works as I expected, please help.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 <tab   
  [routerLink]="['/user/my-account']"
  routerLinkActive 
  #ads="routerLinkActive"
  [active]="ads.isActive">  
</tab>
```

Comment: added, but still showing the first tab instead of third

Comment: are you adding them in an <a> element?? can you show me the html please

Comment: I have added screen shot in my question, I want to make active on the settings tab when user visit 'my setting'  url

Comment: as the example above, delete [routerLink] from tab and add it in the element inside the tab

Comment: and delete the [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158999/discussion-between-sebin-simon-and-fateh-mohamed).

Comment: i updated the answer, i tried to assign the RouterLinkActive instance to a template variable and directly check the isActive status and set active property based on this. this should work

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late reply, but for future people searching:

HTML:

```
  <tabset class="nav nav-tabs">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let template of templates">
      <tab #tab="routerLinkActive" 
           (selectTab)="(!template.disabled || firstSelection) && routeChange(template.appRouterLink)"
           [active]="tab.isActive" 
           [customClass]="template.disabled && template.hideDisabled ?
            'd-none' : template.disabled ? 'disabled' : ''" 
           [heading]="template.labelKey | translate"
           [routerLink]="template.appRouterLink" 
           routerLinkActive="active">
      </tab>
    </ng-container>
  </tabset>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
```

TS:

```
  @ContentChildren(TabsDirective) public templates: QueryList<TabsDirective>;
  private firstSelection = true;

  public constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  public async routeChange(appRouterLink: any[] | string): Promise<any> {
    if (this.firstSelection) {
      this.firstSelection = false;

    } else {
      const route = appRouterLink instanceof Array ? appRouterLink : [appRouterLink];
      this.router.navigate(route, {relativeTo: this.route});
    }
  }
```

And the directive:

```
@Directive({selector: '[appTabs]'})
export class TabsDirective {
  @Input() public disabled: boolean;
  @Input() public hideDisabled: boolean;
  @Input() public labelKey: string;
  @Input() public appRouterLink: any[] | string | null | undefined;
}
```

Usage example:

```
 <app-nav>
   <ng-template [disabled]="!can_see_info" appRouterLink="info"
             appTabs labelKey="INFO"></ng-template>

   <ng-template [disabled]="!can_see_events || !company?.id" appRouterLink="events"
             appTabs labelKey="EVENTS"></ng-template>
 </app-nav>
```

Few notes on why the code is like this:

- If you use the disabled property on tab tag and the initial value is set to true but is later changed, it will dismiss the trigger of select event, which will make the tab not show as selected.
- If you use *ngIf on tab tag, the order of the tabs might get all screwed up if you hide one and later show it again (sort of a FIFO behaviour).

Answer (score 0):

#### This is how you can do tab changes with routing programmatically

**component.html**

```
<tabset>
    <tab *ngFor="let m of menu; let i = index" [active]="m.active" [heading]="m.title" (selectTab)="tabSelected(m.url)">
        <component-a *ngIf="i == 0"></component-a>
        <component-b *ngIf="i == 1"></component-b>
        <component-c *ngIf="i == 2"></component-c>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

**component.ts**

```
  menu: Array<IMenu>
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.initMenu()
    this.onPageLoad()
  }

  initMenu() {
    this.menu = [
      {
        title: 'Tab 1',
        url: '/tab-1',
        active: true   // default active tab
      },
      {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        url: '/tab-2',
        active: false
      },
      {
        title: 'Tab 3',
        url: '/tab-3',
        active: false
      }
    ]
  }

  // activate tab based on url when page loads
  onPageLoad() {
    this.menu.forEach(m => m.active = false)
    let _selected_menu = this.menu?.find(x => x.url.includes(this.router.url))

    if (_selected_menu) {
      _selected_menu.active = true
    }
  }

  // change url when user selects tab
  tabSelected(url: string) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(url)
  }
```